# Is ‘a high level of light’ okay like ‘a high level of brightness’?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is ‘a high level of light’ okay like ‘a high level of brightness’? I want to express something is very bright.

Comment: Both those phrases are awkward. I would use neither. If you [edit] the question to show us a complete sentence or paragraph where you want to say that we may be better able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "the light was intensely bright" or "the light was incredibly bright." Basically, any adverb meaning "extremely" or very will do if put before the word "bright". For a more complex sentence, you could even use a metaphor, as in "the light shone brightly like a stadium at night" or "the brightness of the light was something the likes of which he had never seen" or "The lights were blindingly bright and left spots on his vision."